# Doesn't save changes when using a cookie

Tags: jquery, css, cookies

I have this code for change a text color on page. Switching works good, but the cookie does not save any changes.

Any idea what's wrong?

```
 $(".white").click(function(){
        $('.welcome h1,.box p, .newsletter, .responsive, .beauti, .unlimited,.flex-active').css("color","#ffffff");
         if( $.cookie('color') != undefined) {
            $('.welcome h1,.box p, .newsletter, .responsive, .beauti, .unlimited,').css('color', 'url(' + $.cookie('color') + ')');}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are missing a `});` off the end if that matters. And you have one too many commas here: `.beauti, .unlimited,').css` remove that last one

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `url(xxx)` for colors. [It should be HEX, RGB or HSL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/color_value)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set $.cookie("color", "value"); for saving change.

Comment: Also make sure you save it: 
- for the entire area you need (ie path the cookie is valid for)
- for the duration you need (ie if you want users getting back having the previous color).

Comment: can u see please the demo what is wrong? thanks [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tHPgg/)